# Biblatex - Verbose style : adding (year) to the author-title format

Tags: biblatex

I'm using the verbose-trad1 style for my bibliography. This style (and all verbose style I think) use a shorter author-title format when an item is cited a second time, like this :

1. Johnny (1992). *My life*.
2. Nathan (2015). *Not my life*.
3. Johnny, op. cit.

There are 115 pages in my work and no one will remember what book I am talking about with just the author and this miserable "op cit". So I need the second citation to be with the date, like this :

3. Johnny (1992), op. cit.

Thank you for reading.. please help a poor student with her master's thesis

Here a minimal example

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

 \usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=verbose-trad1,indexing=cite,firstinits=true,dashed=true,citepages=omit]{biblatex}
 \bibliography{example.bib}


 \begin{document}

 This is just filler text\footcite{john_2010}. This is just filler
 text\footcite{nathan_2015}. This is just filler
 text\footcite{john_2010}.

 \end{document}
```

And the example.bbl file :

```
 @book{nathan_2015,     
 Author = {Nathan},     
 Title= {Not my life},  
 Year = {2015}}

 @book{john_2010,   
 Author = {Johnny},
 Title= {My life},  
 Year = {1992}}
```

Comment: Please help the poor helpers by adding a minimal example which could be used for tests.

Comment: Done ! Sorry I didn't think it was necessary :(

Comment: Am I right in thinking you want this style for all subsequent citations?

Comment: Yes absolutely.  I need the full citation for the first, then the "author (date), op.cit" for all of the subsequent citations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the `verbose-trad` styles go together with a `authortitle` style and thus use *titles* to disambiguate references. So "Johnny, *op. cit.*" will only appear if you cite exactly one work by Johnny, as soon as there are more, the `title` field is added to avoid confusion.

Anyway, we can make sure the year is always added.

We first borrow a `authoryear` macro

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
         \printlabeldateextra}}}}
```

And then inject this macro into the relevant places to print the year after the name

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:name}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
  \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:idem}{%
  \bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear, citestyle=verbose-trad1, indexing=cite, giveninits=true, citepages=omit]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
         \printlabeldateextra}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:name}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
  \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:idem}{%
  \bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}

\begin{document}
This is just filler text\footcite{geer}. This is just filler
text\footcite{worman}. This is just filler
text\footcite{geer}.

Text \footcite{knuth:ct:a} an \footcite{knuth:ct:b} again \footcite{knuth:ct:a}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks a lot, you save my thesis :)