# Change footnote citation style

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

I'm quite new to BibLaTeX and i'm trying to modify the verbose-ibid style to my requirements. The Bibliography ist perfect but the footnotes aren't doing all the things I want.

First: In one footnote I cite a inproceeding with an editor but the editor isn't shown. Instead there ist only "—" whereas in the bibliography there is the editor.

Second: The short citation in the footnote is like this: "Author, Title. Pages." 
But I would like to have it like this: "Author Year: Pages."

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english.

EDIT: Here my document:

```
  \documentclass[%
   paper=a4,% 
   paper=portrait, % landscape
   pagesize=auto, % driver
   fontsize=11pt,%
   version=last, %
 ]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{textcomp}    
\usepackage{lmodern}   
\usepackage[bottom,hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}    
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{
    sorting=nyt, % Sort by name, title, year.
    bibwarn=true, %
    bibencoding=inputenc, % (auto, ascii, inputenc, <encoding>)
    isbn=false,%
    url=false,%
    doi=false,%
    eprint=false,%  
    firstinits=false,% Initialien Erzeugen
}%  
\addbibresource{Literatur2.bib}

\begin{document}

\footcite{allkemper14}
\footcite{Haberkamm89}
\footcite[S. 3]{allkemper14}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]    

\end{document}
```

for this Bib-entry:

```
@book{allkemper14,
   author = {Allkemper, Alo and Eke, Norbert Otto},
   title = {Literaturwissenschaft},
   volume = {4., aktualisierte Auflage},
   address = {Paderborn},
   publisher = {Wilhelm Fink},
   year = {2014},
}
```

And the third footnote gives out this: Allkemper und Eke, *Literaturwissenschaft*, S. 3.
But i would like to have this: Allkemper und Eke 2014: S. 3.

Comment: Welcome! We need a small document we can compile to reproduce your situation in order to help you effectively. But you can configure the style for the bibliography and the citations separately using `bibstyle` and `citestyle` in the package options.

Comment: Is [this](http://golatex.de/viewtopic,p,73795.html) perchance a question of yours as well? Please see the almost exact duplicate [BibLaTeX: Making verbose-authoryear fullbibliography at once](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32354/35864) and [Biblatex: First citation as full reference and following citations ibid or - when interrupted - short citation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139158/) or [Biblatex - Verbose style: adding (year) to the author-title format](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/249762/35864).

Comment: Crosspost: http://golatex.de/viewtopic,p,73794.html#73794

Answer (score 3):

Following my solution to  [Biblatex: First citation as full reference and following citations ibid or - when interrupted - short citation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139158/) we can redefine the `cite:short` macro of `verbose-ibid.cbx`

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit*{\nameyeardelim}%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
       \printfield{labelyear}%
       \printfield{extrayear}}}}
```

For this we will have to add `labeldate` to `biblatex`'s options (as in `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-ibid, labelyear]{biblatex}`).

Finally, we redefine a few delimiters in order to get a mere space between name and year and a colon before the page number.

```
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage{lmodern}  
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-ibid, labelyear]{biblatex}    
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit*{\nameyeardelim}%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
       \printfield{labelyear}%
       \printfield{extrayear}}}}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}

\begin{document}
\footcite{geer}
\footcite{worman}
\footcite[3]{geer}

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]